# PHP MySQL Prepared Statements vs Single Query Performance

Tags: php, mysql

I am making tests on performance on my query and I found out that `prepared` statements seem slower than single query. Is this the expected output? Or I'm missing something on prepared statements. I basically prefer prepared statements for security reasons. But it is slower, maybe there's still a way to optimize it more?

I am using 10k records for testing.

Here's my queries:

//QUERY 1 - prepared statements - took `2433` ms

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); 

//prepare our query
$query  = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, address) VALUES (?,?,?)";

//bind parameters
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$statement ->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $address);

//execute each statement
foreach ($user_object_array as $user) {
    $name = $user["name"];
    $email = $user["email"];
    $address = $user["address"];
    $statement->execute();
    $affected_rows += $mysqli->affected_rows;
}

//finally, commit
$mysqli->commit();
```

//QUERY 2 single query - took `600` ms

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user(name,email,address) VALUES ";

foreach ($user_object_array as $user) { 
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $user["name"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $user["email"]);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $user["address"]);
    $sql .= "('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$address."'),";
}

//remove the last comma on string
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);

if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
       $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
} else {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

Comment: The possible reason here is you concat the ad-hoc query and run it once, while with prepare statement, you execute the query 10k times

Comment: You're not really comparing apples and apples. You are executing 10000 queries in your first code, and only one in the second.

Comment: @Nick Do we have any way to make the prepared statement faster? Like same performance on single query? Since, I cannot find any way so far.

Comment: You could build the same type of query, with 10000 sets of `(?,?,?)` and binding 30000 variables. It might still be slower though as you will require time to parse the query and substitute the variables.

Comment: Looks like this is still on bugs list: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73056

Comment: For insert  you could think at batch insert  tecniques

Comment: It has nothing to do with that bug report. 1 query vs. 10000 queries. It's pretty obvious which one is going to be slower. Actually, considering that, it's pretty amazing that the 10000 prepared statements are slower by merely a factor of ~4.